# How to reconstruct moments from aggregated data?

Tags: distributions, lognormal-distribution, moments, aggregation, disaggregation

Let $X_{1\ldots n}$ be a stochastic variable that is log-normal distributed, with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

Now suppose all $X_i$ are aggregated into $Y_{1\ldots m}$ where $Y_1$ is the mean of all $X_i$ that are in the first quantile of $X$, $Y_2$ is the mean of all $X_i$ that are in the second quantile of $X$, etc. I'm using $m=5$, to the quantiles are actually quintiles.

Obviously, I can compute the mean, variance, etc of $Y$, but how do I reconstruct the $\mu$ and $\sigma$ of the original data set? (In my problem, I only have $Y$, not $X$)

I've already found (numerically, using matlab) that for normally distributed data $E(X) = E(Y)$ and that $\sigma(X)/\sigma(Y)=c$, where $c$ is a constant $>1$ depending on $m$. Obviously, for $m\rightarrow\infty$, $c\rightarrow1$. However, for the lognormal case discussed here, this does not work.

Again, my question is: how do I compute $\mu$ and $\sigma$ of $X$, given $Y$?

Comment: Are you asking about how to compute $\mu$ and $\sigma$ in a theoretical sense, given the theoretical values for the $Y_i$, or how to *estimate* $\mu$ and $\sigma$ given *observed* values of the $Y_i$ in an iid sample?